# 3D game special effects, fire, lightning, water, and ice

Tags: xna, graphics, 3d, opengl, directx

I'm working on a 3d game using OpenGL and would like to take it in a fantasy direction.  Specifically I'm thinking of having magic with effects for fire, water, ice, and lightning.  My problem is I have no idea how to create these effects.  Are there any resources for me on how to learn something like this?

Comment: how far did you go with the development so far? I've started to look at the Unity3D framework as its cross-platform including mobile devices and there are a bunch of tutorials for effects there too. www.unity3d.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in to [Particle Systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_system) or particle effects.

Here are some links to tutorials:

[http://gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL:Tutorials:Tutorial_Framework:Particles](http://web.archive.org/web/20111201180849/http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL:Tutorials:Tutorial_Framework:Particles)

http://www.swiftless.com/tutorials/opengl/particles.html

http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=19

Answer (score 1):

First of all try to play with such effects in [UDK](http://udk.com/) Taste there realization in Unreal Engine 3. Then you can read something from [Nvidia SDK](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/9.5/Samples/samples.html) and read math of cook from there [book](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch01.html)